# How do I get the ARN of an imported aws_db_instance?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Suppose I import an RDS instance like so:

```
data "aws_db_instance" "main" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.main_rds
}
```

How do I get the ARN?

```
# Doesn't work
data.aws_db_instance.main.arn
```

Comment: No, but that wasn't my entire question :) It doesn't work because `arn` is not an attribute of the `aws_db_instance` data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official Docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_instance#db_instance_arn):
The correct property would be `db_instance_arn`, so you would use it like so:

```
data.aws_db_instance.main.db_instance_arn
```